# Reading Client Side Excel file in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am new to Flex. I need to read a excel file from the client side and show it to data grid.
I tried searching but could not find something relevant. 
Please give some pointers, if somebody has done something on this.
Thanks in advance.
Aj

Answer (score 0):

[as3xls](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/) is the only project I'm aware of for accessing Excel Data in a Flex App.